# Two part question about submitting bluetooth-enabled apps for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, app-store, plist

I have a couple questions about submitting blue-tooth enabled apps on the iPhone.

I want to first say that bluetooth is merely an option in the application.  The application does not completely rely on bluetooth as there are many modes the user can go in.

First, do they require you to have the "peer-peer" key set in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities  even if bluetooth interface options can be disabled or hidden for non-bluetooth enabled devices?  Basically, it's just an OPTION in the game and there are many other modes the player can play..  Does Apple not allow you to do that?  I'm just curious, because it seems like something they would do.

Adding to that, how do you check for it's functionality at runtime?  In essence, how do you check UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities at runtime.   I'm aware of checking iPhone device types, so would that be a proper way of going about it?

I'm also sort of unaware which devices can run bluetooth gamekit, there doesn't seem to be a proper reference at the SDK site, or I'm unable to find it.

Thanks for reading!

[edit] I can confirm the existance of somebody rejected for submitting a bluetooth enabled app which didn't work on a iPhone 2G.. Of course, they didn't say if that was the MAIN function of the app, though.

Comment: To check for specific APIs just use `[instance respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]` for C functions use `ACFunction != NULL`. Don't check for the hardware you're on, check for the API's existence.

Comment: Ah.  In this case, GameKit will respond on a 2G iPhone with a 'Device is not supported' message.  I don't really know which API to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For devices that do not support this capability, see the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1):

> Bluetooth networking is not supported
>   on the original iPhone or the
>   first-generation iPod Touch. It is
>   also not supported in Simulator.

If this is an optionally-enabled feature, you might be able to get by with disabling it for the appropriate devices by detecting first-generation iPhones and iPod touches using code like [Jeff LaMarche's UIDevice category](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/device-detection-redux.html).  If you hide this option when running on unsupported devices, if a reviewer happens to use one of those devices they won't even see that there's something nonfunctional.

Comment: My concern with that approach is the app will not have the peer-peer key, and people have been rejected for not setting that.  That key, of course, will make it so your app will not be sellable to 2G iPhones from what I understand.  So from what I understand, there's a bit of a reviewer perception problem there.  Of course, I'll add notes where I can but at the same time I wanted to know if you can indeed alter functionality (seems such an honest thing, but i dont know about the policies)